# Dell PowerConnect 6224P VoIP

Tags: switch, dhcp, dell

We have an issue where the IP phones are getting DHCP IP's from the Data VLAN.

Data - VLAN 10
VoIP - VLAN 15

As of right now, we are just working on one port before deploying a solution to the entire network. This is what we had originall:

```
interface ethernet 3/g46
switchport mode general
switchport general pvid 10
switchport general allowed vlan add 10
switchport general allowed vlan add 15 tagged
switchport general allowed vlan remove 1
exit
!
```

I've changed it to this:

```
console#show running-config interface ethernet 3/g46
switchport mode general
switchport general allowed vlan add 10
switchport general allowed vlan remove 1
voice vlan 15
```

Help is greatly appreciated. I am much more used to HP style configuration where you work with VLANs, not interfaces...

Comment: Run `show ip vlan` to see if VLAN routing is enabled.  Is interface 3/g46 the only port you want to be a member of the voice vlan right now?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

[VOICE VLAN SUPPORT IN THE DELL™ POWERCONNECT™ 6200](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pwcnt/en/pwcnt_voice_vlan_support.pdf)

Consult the list of requirements (11 of them) on page 3. Specifically, `voice vlan` has to be enabled on the switch, and LLDP-MED has to be enabled (as that's what tells the phone what to use.)